# How to restore Gnome Shell styling in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-shell

How do you restore default styling to Gnome-Shell in Ubuntu 18.04 and purge all the custom Unity-eske changes specific to Ubuntu?

I know there are [a lot of guides](https://itsfoss.com/vanilla-gnome-ubuntu/) explaining this, but none of them completely accomplish the task.

I've re-installed gnome-session. I've reset the GDM screen. I've re-logged in under the Gnome. I've used Tweaks to change the default theme.

The last thing still broken is the top bar. It should be black, but it retains the slate-gray styling from the Unity theme.

Comment: did you install unity after a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04? desktop session is Ubuntu or Gnome??

Comment: DId you check whether the "User themes"extension is disabled? Then Gnome Shell surely should be using the default theme.